# Why use memcpy() in C

Tags: c, memcpy

This might be a very stupid question but i don't understand this:

If i have:

```
void* a;
void* b;
```

And I want to implement a generic swap function, why can't I do this:

```
void swap(void* a, void* b)
{
   void* temp = malloc(sizeof(*a));
   *a = *b;
   *b = *temp;
   free(temp);
}
```

Thank you

I added this later on:

So i understand now why it is impossible but now i have another question:
Since
    sizeof(*a)
is undefined, someone told me i could do this:

```
#define SWAP(a,b) \
{ \
   void* temp = malloc(sizeof(*a)); \
   memcpy(temp , a , sizeof(*a)); \ 
   memcpy(a, b, sizeof(*a)); \
   memcpy(b, temp, sizeof(*a));
   free(temp);
}
```

of course i assume a and b are of the same type.
Why will this solution work?
thank you

Comment: What is `sizeof *a` when `a` is of type `void*`?

Comment: I don't even see a `memcpy` here...

Comment: and what are `x` and `y`?!

Comment: @pmr She thinks the code she wrote is an _alternative_ to memcpy, and she's asking why she can't use that alternative.

Comment: @pmr OP try to NOT use memcpy, that's his question (sort of).

Comment: If you have a second question then please start a new question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot dereference a `void *`, there is no information about the type of data it's pointing at. So your code won't compile, which is why you cannot do that.

That's the *point* of `void *`, it's a "pointer to anything", and there is absolutely no additional information available if you don't add it yourself.

If I have:

```
char a; /* size 1 */
int b;  /* assume size 4 */
```

and call:

```
swap(&a, &b);  /* assuming it compiled */
```

*All* information the function gets is the address of the two variables. There's no way for the function (or the compiler) to magically follow those pointers backward and figure out what the sizes of the pointed-to values are. None.

Comment: @Daniella Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: if i would like to create
void swap (char*, char*); will (*a) = (*b) work ?

Comment: @Daniella Sure, but it would only copy a single character, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This way you only "copy" the pointer address but not the actual data. once after you freed temp, y becomes an invalid address. Besides that you're not using a or b in any case

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 2nd question, your SWAP() macro will still NOT work as intended if you pass `void*` pointers to it. Or for that matter, if you pass two pointers of different types. 
It will work for something like this:

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
char c = '0', d = '1';
SWAP(&a, &b);
SWAP(&c, &d);
```